# CsvHelper : Writing List<string> to CSV

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I want to know how to write a List to a CSV using CsvHelper. I have taken a look [here](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/837).

I have the following properties in the CSV Class

```cs
public class CSV
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public List<string> Header1 { get; set; }
    public string Header2 { get; set; }
    public string Header3 { get; set; }
    public string Header4 { get; set; }
    public long? Header5 { get; set; }
    public long? Header6 { get; set; }
    public long? Header7 { get; set; }
    public string Header8 { get; set; }
    public List<string> Header9 { get; set; }
    public List<string> Header10 { get; set; }
    public List<string> Header11 { get; set; }
}
```

Writing to the CSV

```cs
var records = new List<CSV>
{
    new CSV { Header1 = new List<string>{ "value1", "value2" } }
};

using (var writer = new StreamWriter("path\\to\\file.csv"))
using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
{
    csv.WriteRecords(records);
}
```

The end result should look like this

```
Header1
value1,value2
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to put a file name in here `using (var writer = new StreamWriter(@"c:\test.csv"))`

Comment: `Header1 = "value1","value2"` looks odd… how can you assign two string values to ONE string? I am guessing you want `Header1 = "value1, value2"`? Even if `Header1` is a `List<string>` the assignment will not work. In that case you would want… `Header1 = new List<string> { "value1","value2"}`. It is unclear what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Andy I added the file.  Thank you

Comment: @JohnG The issue is the header is still not written to the CSV file

Comment: @JohnG I have added the class. Please see

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing you are looking for something like this. This will create a comma separated string from the `Header1` list.

```cs
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {        
        var records = new List<CSV>
        {
            new CSV { Id = 1, Header1 = new List<string>{ "value1", "value2" } }
        };

        using (var csv = new CsvWriter(Console.Out, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        {
            csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<CSVMap>();
            csv.WriteRecords(records);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class CSVMap : ClassMap<CSV>
{
    public CSVMap()
    {
        AutoMap(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        Map(m => m.Header1).Convert(args => string.Join(",", args.Value.Header1)).Index(0);
    }
}

public class CSV
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public List<string> Header1 { get; set; }
}
```

Giving you an output of

```
Id,Header1
1,"value1,value2"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer David. Header 1 now appears at the end of the file. The CSV headers are not in order now.

Comment: Try `Map(m => m.Header1).ConvertUsing(row => string.Join(",", row.Header1)).Index(0);` Otherwise you may have to map each column individually `Map(m => m.Id);` `Map(m => m.Header2);` in the order that you want them in, rather than use `AutoMap(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Comment: @DavidSpecht Is there any way to write the list of strings to multiple columns with the same header name?

Comment: @Farshan See my answer to your question on GitHub. https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/837#issuecomment-822486362

Comment: @DavidSpecht thank you, I guess I have to write the headers manually inside a loop since the length of the list of strings are dynamic.

Comment: For anyone coming across this answer with CsvHelper after version [20.0.0](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/change-log/), `.ConvertUsing` is now `.Convert`. Also,  `csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<CSVMap>();` would be `csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<CSVMap>();`