# CSVHelper doesn't store HashSet fields

Tags: c#, csv, missing-data, hashset, csvhelper

I'm working on a software project where the program has a data storage and a UI that lets you manipulate this data. I use multiple data types, some of which contain HashSets. I don't do anything complex, it's just HashSet<int> in each case, but when I try to save a list of these records, only the primitives and enums get written to the csv file, the hashsets are completely ignored.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```cs
using CsvHelper;
using CsvHelper.Configuration.Attributes;

internal class Program {

    private static readonly List<Record> records = new();

    private static void Main(string[] args) {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");

        records.Add(new Record() { Id = 1, Values = new() { 1, 2, 3, 4 } });
        records.Add(new Record() { Id = 2, Values = new() { 5, 6, 7, 8 } });
        records.Add(new Record() { Id = 3, Values = new() { 9, 10, 11, 12 } });

        using StreamWriter sw = new("records.csv");
        using CsvWriter csv = new(sw, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        csv.WriteRecords(records);
    }

}

public class Record {
    [Name("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Name("values")]
    public HashSet<int> Values { get; set; }
}
```

This is what I expect the csv file to look like (curly braces are optional):

[image: CSV data populated]

This is what I actually get:

[image: CSV data missing]

Comment: [CsvHelper : Writing List<string> to CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63920336/3744182) looks like it should do what you want.  That question was about `List<string>` but it should be possible to map any collection of primitives such as `HashSet<int>` similarly.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CsvHelper : Writing List<string> to CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63895114/csvhelper-writing-liststring-to-csv).  @dbc is correct.  I just tried it with `HashSet<int>` and it works the same as with `List<string>`.

Comment: Yes, that works for this simple example, but in my main application, I have a base record class tha contains save/load functions and a single ID field. Several derived classes contain multiple HashSet<int> fields, so I need a way to map HashSet<int> in general and not a specific field of a specific type. So like if I add a HashSet<int> field to a record class it just works without any other code modification

Comment: @AnthonySpendlove - then please [edit] your question to include your actual requirements, including a [mcve].

Comment: Nvm, found the solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/48088288/4500564